# vb 6 showing timeout expired while executing stored procedure

Tags: vb6, sql-server-2005-express

when i tried to execute this stored procedure it is giving me timeout expired error here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_rptExpMed]
(
  @Stocname as varchar(100),
  @date varchar(40),
  @Mode int
)
as
begin
if @Mode=1
    begin
    select DISTINCT  Em.*,M.DrugName,m.Category
    --,rate 
    from ExpiryMed Em inner join medicinaldrugs M on Em.Drugid=M.drugId
    LEFT join Purchase22011_2012 P on em.DrugID = P.ItemID and Em.batch=p.BatchNo
    order by M.DrugName,Em.Batch
    end
if @Mode=2
    begin
    select DISTINCT Em.*,M.DrugName,m.Category
    --,rate
     from ExpiryMed Em inner join medicinaldrugs M on Em.Drugid=M.drugId
    LEFT join Purchase22011_2012 P on em.DrugID = P.ItemID and Em.batch=p.BatchNo
    where ExpDate<@date
    order by M.DrugName,Em.Batch
    end
end
```

what is wrong in this. can anyone suggest me a way to avoid this timeout expired error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be the case that the table(s) you are querying from in your procedure hold a lock due to open/uncommitted transaction on them. Try using a `NOLOCK` table hint along with the table name like

```
select DISTINCT  Em.*,M.DrugName,m.Category
from ExpiryMed Em WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join medicinaldrugs M WITH (NOLOCK) on Em.Drugid=M.drugId
LEFT join Purchase22011_2012 P WITH (NOLOCK) on em.DrugID = P.ItemID 
and Em.batch=p.BatchNo
order by M.DrugName,Em.Batch
```

You can as well set the transaction isolation level to [READ UNCOMMITTED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your time, but still it is giving me the same error

Comment: Strange and shouldn't be. You will have to use `NOLOCK` for all your quries in procedure (OR) set the transaction isolation level globally. Go through the linked MSDN doc to see how.

Comment: as you said i set the transaction isolation globally and it worked